# Meaning of 3P+N/2 in circuit breaker

Tags: three-phase, circuit-protection, circuit-breaker

In the following selection table of Legrand DPX3 three phase molded circuit breakers (Legrand 422000 to 422013) along with the familiar 3P and 4P circuit breakers, there are **3P+N/2** circuit breakers (such as the [Legrand 422011](https://www.electricautomationnetwork.com/en/legrand/422011-legrand-dpx3-630-mt-3pn-2-400a-36ka)).

No information is provided in the technical, selection or product pages.

What is the meaning of that notation?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After searching, it appears that some manufacturers including Legrand use **3P+N/2**, the other manufacturers use **3P+N**.  ([Ref for nomenclature](https://www.nader-circuit-breaker.com/blog-technology-breaker-1p-2p-3p-4p-what-s-the-difference-how-to-choose.html).)

It appears to be saying that the neutral has half the current rating of the main poles.  You'll have to check what other manufacturers' ratings for 3P+N devices are from their datasheets.

From [data sheet](https://assets.legrand.com/pim/NP-FT-GT/F01958EN03%20DPX3630_MT_ENG%20v1.0.pdf), page 4

[image]

Comment: `it appears that Legrand is the only manufacturer to use 3P+N/2` Schneider uses the same convention as well. N/2 means half neutral protection, as you stated in your answer. In some applications where the phases don't have balanced loading, due to some operational reasons neutral wire may not have the same size as the phase wires. So half protection might be enough.

Comment: Thanks @RohatKılıç, I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Meaning of the terms 2P2d, 3P3d, 4P3d, 4P4d, 4P3d+N/2 or 4P3d+OSN...?
The first number corresponds to the number of poles.
The second digit corresponds to the number of protected poles.
The first letter means "Pole".
The second letter means "trigger".

Examples:
4P3d is a 4-pole (four-pole) trip unit with 3 protected poles (not the neutral).
4P3d+ **N**/**2** is a 4-pole (four-pole) trip unit with 3 protected poles and the neutral has a **half-phase section**.
4P3d+**OSN** is a 4-pole (four-pole) trip unit with 3 protected poles and with oversized neutral protection (**OverSizeNeutral**).

That table defines the range and models of the [series](https://assets.legrand.com/pim/NP-FT-GT/F01958EN03%20DPX3630_MT_ENG%20v1.0.pdf)

[image]